# Jetpack Compose, persist and retrieve data (Flow<List<Item>>) Error : lateinit property appData has not been initialized

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, roomdb

Hello helpful community,

I have been working on an application where I am having difficulties understanding how to persist and retrieve a Flow<List>> in a room database. I believe what I wrote in the ViewModel and MainActivity classes is wrong and I cannot figure out the proper way to do it. I tried to persist from the main activity but I receive the following error :

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property appData has not been initialized at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3822) at
```

Model

```
@Entity(tableName="items")
data class (Item
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val itemId: String,
    @StringRes val title: Int,
    @StringRes val description: Int,
    @DrawableRes val drawable: Int
)
```

Dao

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {


    @Query("SELECT * FROM items")
    fun getItems(): Flow<List<Item>>


    @Query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=:itemId")
    fun getItem(itemId: String): Flow<Item>

    @Insert
    fun insertItem(item: Item)


    @Insert
    suspend fun insertAll(items: List<Item>)


}
```

Repository

```
@Singleton
class ItemRepository @Inject constructor (
    private val itemDao : ItemDao,

    ) {
    fun getItems(): Flow<List<Item>> {
      return itemDao.getItems()
    }

    fun getItem(itemId: String) = itemDao.getItem(itemId)

    suspend fun insertItem(item : Item) {
        return itemDao.insertItem(item)
    }

    suspend fun insertItems(item : List<Item>) {
       return  workoutDao.insertAll(item)
    }
```

ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class ItemListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val itemRepository: ItemRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _items = MutableStateFlow<List<Item>>(emptyList())
    val items = _items.asStateFlow()

    init {
        loadTask()
    }

    private fun loadTask() {
        viewModelScope.launch() {
            itemRepository.getItems()
        }
    }
```

DatabaseModule

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAppDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            DATABASE_NAME
        )
       .build()
    }



        @Provides
    fun provideItemDao(appDatabase: AppDatabase): ItemDao
        = appDatabase.itemDao()
```

AppDatabase

```
@Database(entities = [Item::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun itemDao(): ItemDao
```

ItemListScreen

```
@Composable
fun ItemListScreen(
    onItemClick: (Item) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: ItemListViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    val items by viewModel.items.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    ItemListScreen(items = items, modifier, onItemClick = onItemClick)
}
```

MainActivity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var appData: AppDatabase

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        setContent {
            FitTestAppTheme {
                ItemApp()
            }
        }


        val item = Item("1",R.string.title,R.string.description, R.drawable.image)

        if (::appData.isInitialized) {}

        appData.itemDao().insertItem(item)

    }
}
```

Error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fittestapp/com.example.fittestapp.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property appData has not been initialized
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3822)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3963)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2468)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
                                                                                                    Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property appData has not been initialized
                                                                                                        at com.example.fittestapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:41)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8621)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8599)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3804)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3963) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

Comment: It says "*appData has not been initialized*". Have tried fixing that by actually initializing `appData`? Currently, you only declare it, but it never gets a value assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `@Inject` annotation on your appData, this will tell the `hilt` to inject AppDatabase from your `DatabaseModule`.

**Edit:**
Also do not call database operations on main thread, you can allow it by `Room.databaseBuilder().allowMainThreadQueries()` or wrap the insert with thread or coroutine.

I am not sure if you want to use `Flow` or `StateFlow`, both ways are valid and it depends on context of your project, so i implemented both of them:

Updated `ItemsDao`:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface ItemDao {
    
    @Query("SELECT * FROM items")
    fun getItemsFlow(): Flow<List<Item>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM items")
    fun getItems(): List<Item>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=:itemId")
    fun getItem(itemId: String): Flow<Item>

    @Insert
    fun insertItem(item: Item)
    
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertAll(items: List<Item>)
    
}
```

Updated `ItemsRepository`:

```kotlin
@Singleton
class ItemRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val itemDao: ItemDao,

    ) {
    fun getItems(): List<Item> {
        return itemDao.getItems()
    }

    fun getItemsFlow(): Flow<List<Item>> {
        return itemDao.getItemsFlow()
    }

    fun getItem(itemId: String) = itemDao.getItem(itemId)

    suspend fun insertItem(item: Item) {
        return itemDao.insertItem(item)
    }

    suspend fun insertItems(item: List<Item>) {
         return workoutDao.insertAll(item)
    }
}
```

Updated `ItemViewModel`:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class ItemListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val itemRepository: ItemRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _items = MutableStateFlow<List<Item>>(emptyList())
    val items = _items.asStateFlow()

    //Using the flow returned by itemsRepository directly
    val itemsFlow = itemRepository.getItemsFlow()

    init {
        loadTask()
    }


    fun addItem(item: Item) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                itemRepository.insertItem(item = item)
                loadTask()
            }
        }
    }

    fun loadTask() {
        viewModelScope.launch() {
            //Loading items as simple list and setting it as _items value
            _items.value = itemRepository.getItems()
        }
    }
}
```

Now for the `MainActivity` i removed `appData` and using viewModel only. It's better to have clean structure of project. I made up collection for bot `flow` and `stateFlow` items. After the item is inserted, items are reloaded.

Also keep in mind that you **can't insert two items with same id**, that's why it looks like item is not being inserted. You probably inserted it before.

Updated `MainActivity`:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {


    private val viewModel: ItemListViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        setContent {
            val itemsFromStateFlow by viewModel.items.collectAsState()
            val itemsFromFlow by viewModel.itemsFlow.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
            StackOverflowTheme {
                Scaffold(containerColor = Color.White) { paddingValues ->

                    Column {
                        Text(text = "Items from state flow")
                        LazyColumn {
                            items(items = itemsFromStateFlow) {
                                Text(text = it.itemId)
                            }
                        }
                        Text(text = "Items from flow")
                        LazyColumn {
                            items(items = itemsFromFlow) {
                                Text(text = it.itemId)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        val item = Item("1",R.string.title,R.string.description, R.drawable.image)


        //insert
        viewModel.addItem(item = item)
        //refresh data
        viewModel.loadTask()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. It seems nothing is getting inserted. I am also having doubts about how to fetch the data from the viewmodel. I also realized I didn't assign anything to the variable in the viewmodel. Should I insert and retrieve the data from the viewmodel? How could I implement this? Thank you

Comment: @Patrick I Updated my answer. Please take a look at it and let me know if it helped or not.